# Server fails to read data from a socket when it is full

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a LINUX based server application that is reading from a socket that is full (I determined that it is full by performing a Wireshark capture and noticing that on the TCP connection, there was a TCP ZeroWindow, which means that the receiving socket buffer is full).

For some reason, the server gets into a state where it is no longer able to read the data in the full socket receive buffer and since this piece of code is running in a loop, it remains in this state indefinitely and the socket connection remains open.

In order to get the data from the socket, my application is using a combination of:

```
ppoll
ioctl
recv
```

(executed in this order). For example:

```
lPollRes =ppoll (&lPollFd, 1, &lTimeOut, NULL);
ioctl (aSocket, FIONREAD, &lNbBytesToRead)
recv (aSocket, apBuffer, lNbBytesToRead, 0)
```

Appropriate error checking is done and stuff and it is worth noting that ppoll is configured with a timeout of 1 second so that it is not suppose to hang there indefinitely.

I also tried to figure out if it's possible that the file descriptor that I am listening on for the socket has erroneously fallen into a state where it is not ready to process I/O, but I have no way of determining this (at least to my knowledge).

It is also worth noting that this behaviour does not reproduce itself very often.  In fact, it is reproducible, but it takes many thousands of connections to reproduce it from time to time.

So I'm looking for a possible explanations to see why this may occur.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `1lnbBytesToread` when in it is in this state. Guess it is zero? Why not use a debugger to check it out.

Comment: The FIONREAD step is redundant. recv() will return the number of bytes read. Just remove it.

Comment: @EdHeal the value of lNbBytesToRead is indeed 0 (zero).  I will try the debugger, but I'm not sure what would be useful to check for?

Comment: @bbazso Just find out when it becomes zero and why. It means that the server is no longer in the position to receive any data. Hence your problem. You have socket constipation.